# `newtxtext` package released at 2021/05/16 gave an error `! Incomplete ifx; all text was ignored after line 3.`

Tags: newtx

My environment is `Ubuntu 20.04` + `TeX Live 2021`

Here is my MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}[2021/05/16]
\begin{document}
    hi
\end{document}
```

the error said

```
! Incomplete ifx; all text was ignored after line 3.
<inserted text> 
                fi 
l.112 ...\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault
```

Here is the whole log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.5.22)  23 MAY 2021 13:41
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-05-11>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count179
\c@section=\count180
\c@subsection=\count181
\c@subsubsection=\count182
\c@paragraph=\count183
\c@subparagraph=\count184
\c@figure=\count185
\c@table=\count186
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxtext.sty
Package: newtxtext 2021/05/16 v1.65

`newtxtext' v1.65, 2021/05/16 Text macros taking advantage of TeX-Gyre Termes f
onts (msharpe)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2020/07/21 v1.0e Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \swshape on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sscshape on input line 39.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ulcshape on input line 41.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsw on input line 47.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textssc on input line 48.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textulc on input line 49.
)
\ntx@fs=\dimen139

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count187
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count188
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count189
\decimalpart=\count190
)
Package: xstring 2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+ntxtlf on input line
 112.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/t1ntxtlf.fd
File: t1ntxtlf.fd 2021/05/07 v1.1 font definition file for T1/ntx/tlf
)
! Incomplete ifx; all text was ignored after line 3.
<inserted text> 
                fi 
l.112 ...\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault
                                                  
? x
 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1549 strings out of 478836
 20936 string characters out of 5855605
 313593 words of memory out of 5000000
 19240 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403430 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 50i,0n,55p,264b,64s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: I can't confirm that. Using that same version of the `newtx` package, I get no errors.

Comment: well, I use `ubuntu 20.04`, maybe yours is `windows`?

Comment: Is, I use Windows (and MiKTeX).

Comment: OK, then I'll have some linux users to test this issue.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598200/35864. (But turns out things are bit more confusing on MikTeX. I *thought* I had gotten this error before, but now I can't reproduce it even though the package claims to be `v1.65`.)

Comment: I met another problem. I saw the latest version of `newtx` on ctan.org is 1.652 2021-05-22, but I can't get any updates through `sudo tlmgr update newtx`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the current version in TeX Live is 1.651. 1.652 apparently hasn't made it from CTAN to TeX Live yet. (It probably will do so tonight [central European time]. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597966/35864 for which steps are involved in getting a package to TeX Live and why it may take a few days.) That said, I'd have thought you'd get at least v1.651, but maybe your mirror is behind. You might want to try again if you still have v1.65.

Comment: You probably just need to wait a bit. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597966/what-steps-does-a-code-package-follow-until-it-can-be-installed-by-tlmgr

Comment: this was reported here yesterday

Comment: On closer inspection, it turns out that the fix I linked still has issues (I removed the link to avoid confusion), so you will have to wait for v1.652, which is not in TeX Live yet. Confusingly both v1.65 and v1.651 announce themselves as v1.65 to TeX.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598200/new-newtxtext-bug-incomplete-infx